# Change the default endpoint for a docker image

Tags: docker

For a docker image the endpoint is like `http://$hostname:$port/`.

Can I change this default behavior to change it `http://$hostname:$port/v1` ?

I have 2 images hosted but both reside in root context `"/"`, I want one of the images to be available in`'/v1'` instead of `'/'`.Is this possible?

I am trying to set up something like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSSwV.png)

Comment: Isn't that the business of the application running in the container? Or do you have some gateway running in front of the containers?

Answer (score 0):

I'll simplify it for you.

Firstly,`http://$hostname:$port/` is your endpoint if you are not making any service from your container (using docker-compose or docker swarm).

Secondly, your endpoints are already different and distinguishable. If your first container is published on port `8000`, then you cannot run another container published on `8000`, so if you are running another container successfully, it's definitely running on some other port.Thus you can have both on root context.

Thirdly, If you want to access both the images through the same hostname as well as port, distinguishable only by context, you need to deploy an nginx container (or a load-balancer) that does this routing for you - at an application level.

Comment: .Thanks for the reply ,  I am trying to set up something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSSwV.png

Comment: In your load balancer, you need to setup rules which route your 'v1' context to the target group on port 8081 and '/' context on 8080. You will access the groups like: http(s)://$load_blancer_hostname/v1 and http(s)://$load_blancer_hostname/ . Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: I tried this before posting here. But when I tried /v1 it says page not found 404 , as the application on port 8081 is running at '/' and tehre is no exposure to /v1 from the container in port 8081

Comment: You will have to route v1 to application port 8080 and not 8081 (already occupied by '/').